# Continuous proportional data in GLMM

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, proportion, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have the data with dependent variable which is continuous proportional data, like 2% leaf area was eaten by insect or 3% protein in milk. The data contains some 0, and most of data ranges from 0 to 0.5, without 1.

I know count proportion data can be used in generalized linear model with binomial family. But I don’t have a denominator or count data in my dependent variable, I wonder how to apply this continuous proportion data in generalized linear mixed-effect model. Is it suitable to use glmm here? I found some similar questions in the web, but their data actually was count proportion or have a denominator.

Another solution I found in some papers is convert my proportion data with logit transform (Warton & Hui, 2011), then use the linear mixed-effect model. But I am curious how to use the continuous proportional data in GLMM.